# Unpack a dictionary with key value that could be a list

Tags: python, pyspark

I am not sure whether I am asking this in a correct way or not but I am having trouble understanding how to unpack a dictionary key value which could be of list type.

What I am basically trying to achieve is to have a function that can groupBy a dataframe in PySpark, but the aggregation condition can have multiple values in it.

```
def readfilegrouped(**groupargs):
    """Group the dataframe based on the conditions"""

    dfgrouped = groupargs['groupingdf'].groupBy(groupargs['aggcol']).agg(groupargs['aggcond'])
    return dfgrouped
```

In the above function I want to be able to pass multiple conditions for aggregation. Something like mentioned below:

```
    groupargs = {'groupingdf':members, 'aggcol':"MEMBERID", 'aggcond':F.countDistinct(F.col("MEMBERID")).alias("DISTINCT_MEMBERID"), F.sum(F.col("TRANSACTIONS")).alias("TOTALTRANSACTIONS")}
    membersgrouped = readfilegrouped(**groupargs)
```

Members table:

```
MEMBERID  TRANSACTIONS   DATE
 M1          2           01/01
 M1          3           01/02
 M2          5           02/01
 M3          1           01/01
 M3          2           01/02
```

Result I am looking for:

```
 MEMBERID  DISTINCT_MEMBERID  TOTALTRANSACTIONS
   M1          1               5
```

The closest I came to was using a `defaultdict` to do it but I am not sure how to define it correctly while calling the function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `list` can't be a key in `dict`. Do you mean tuple?

Comment: I want it as the value of a dictionary key, if you look at what I am trying to achieve above, I am trying to do multiple aggregations with 1 key of a dictionary and then unpack that dictionary while calling the function.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you want?

Comment: That's exactly what I showed above. I am not sure what else is needed. Basically I want to pass multiple conditions while aggregating.

Comment: provide some sample data (and output desired). what are the values of `members`, etc.  also, did you mean `membersgrouped = readfilegrouped(**args)`, instead of `**groupargs` parameter?

Comment: Edited the question.